# How to read subject from inbox selenium web driver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, inbox, subject

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"io-ox-login-username\"]")).sendKeys("leads@xyz.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"io-ox-login-password\"]")).sendKeys("abc2123");

        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"io-ox-login-button\"]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='folder-label']//div[contains(text(),'Inbox')]")).click();

    List<WebElement> a = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='io.ox/mail']"));
        System.out.println(a.size());
```

Comment: List<WebElement> a not reading inbox

Comment: we cannot answer your question, since your question is for a specific website. Specify from which website you want to read the subject line

Comment: What is the value of a.size() ? can you check with isEmpty() also. Update me with the results to solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getAttribute("value");`

assuming `"//*[@id='io.ox/mail']"` is your inbox..

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='io.ox/mail']").getAttribute("value");
```

should work, if not change the By element for the right one.

Comment: you can't use getAttribute() method on list collection type.

Comment: thats the thing. i dont think findElements should be used at all.

Comment: findElements has it's own business to run , it should be used.